# Add eight thousand line in one commit

Tags: linux, windows, perl, sql-insert, query-performance

I have a log file, perl script who took the log file and transcript the log file, i want to send this all line (eight thousand line) in one commit

my script:

```
# Connect to the database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:database=DB;host=>IP",
    "hostname", 'password',
    {'RaiseError' => 1,'AutoCommit'=> 0}
);

    open (FILE, 'file.log');
    while (<FILE>) {

        ($word1, $word2, $word3, $word4, $word5, $word6, $word7, $word8, $word9, $word10, $word11, $word12, $word13, $word14) = split(" ");

        $word13 =~ s/[^\d.]//g;
        if ($word2 eq "Feb") {
                $word2 = "02"  
        }

        print "'$word5-$word2-$word3 $word4', $word11, $word13 \n";

        eval {
            #on peut utiliser insert mais il y aura des doublons et ici on est dans une table unique
            my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_query` (time, cstep, time_in_seconde) VALUES('$word5-$word2-$word3 $word4', $word11, $word13);");

            #print $sth->rows . " rows found.\n";
            #$sth->finish;          

            # do inserts, updates, deletes, queries here
            #$sth->execute() or die "execution failed: $dbh->errstr()";
            $sth->execute() or die "execution failed: $dbh->errstr()";
            $dbh->commit();

        };

        ### If something went wrong...

    }
}

$dbh->disconnect();
```

thanks

Comment: So `Feb` is converted to `02`, but what about March?

Comment: What is the problem or question?

Comment: my question is how to put thousand line in one time

Comment: Not sure why this was closed as unclear. The OP is asking how to add multiple rows as one transaction, and the answer covers that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For better performance, you want to simplify your code and move as many code as possible out of the loop :

- `prepare` the statement out of the loop, using bind parameters : the statement is always the same, only bind parameters get to change
- `commit` out of the loop : this will increase performance and also has the advantage of making your process *atomic*. As all changes occur within the same database transaction, either all lines will be processed (and commited), or, if a failure occurs on any line, no line at all will be commited. While implementing this optimization you need to watch for resource usage on your database (this will typically require more space in the `UNDO` tablespace) ; if resources are not enough, either increase them or commit every Nth record (with `N` being as high as possible)
- avoid `print`ing inside the loop unless your really need it (I commented that line)
- you are building a connection with `RaiseError` attribute enabled, but then you ignore errors that can occur at `execute`. If this is really what you want, then just disable the `RaiseError` attribute on the statement handler, and remove the `eval` around `execute`

Other considerations in terms of coding practices :

- always `use strict` and `use warnings`
- use an array to store parsed data instead of a list of scalars : *could* make your code faster and *will* make it more readable

Code :

```
use strict;
use warnings;

# Connect to the database.
my $dbh = DBI->connect(
    "DBI:mysql:database=DB;host=>IP",
    "hostname", 'password',
    {'RaiseError' => 1,'AutoCommit'=> 0}
);

# prepare the insert statement
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_query` (time, cstep, time_in_seconde) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");
$sth->{RaiseError} = 0;

open (my $file, 'file.log') or die "could not open : $!";
while (<$file>) {
    my @words = split / /;
    $words[12] =~ s/[^\d.]//g;
    if ($words[1] eq "Feb") {
            $words[1] = "02" ;
    }

    # print "'$words[4]-$words[1]-$words[2] $words[3]', $words[10], $words[12] \n";
    $sth->execute( "$words[4]-$words[1]-$words[2] $words[3]", $words[10], $words[12] );

}

$dbh->commit;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

The last solution, that would probably perform even faster than this one, is to use [DBI method `execute_array`](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#execute_array) to perform bulk database inserts. Attribute `ArrayTupleFetch` can be used to provide a code reference that DBI will invoke everytime it is ready to perform the next `INSERT` : this code reference should read the next file line and provide an array reference of values suitable for `INSERT`. When the file is exhausted, the sub should return undef, which will indicate DBI that the bulk process is completed.

Code :

```
#!/usr/local/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

# open the file
open (my $file, 'log.file') or die "could not open : $!";

# connect the database
my $dbh = DBI->connect("DBI:mysql:database=DB;host=ip", "hostname", 'password', {'RaiseError' => 1,'AutoCommit'=> 0});

# prepare the INSERT statement
my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_query` (time, cstep, time_in_seconde) VALUES(?, ?, ?)");

# run bulk INSERTS
my $tuples = $sth->execute_array({ 
    ArrayTupleStatus => \my @tuple_status,
    ArrayTupleFetch => sub {
        my $line = <$file>;
        return unless $line;
        my @words = split / /;
        # ... do anything you like with the array, then ...
        return [ "$words[4]-$words[1]-$words[2] $words[3]", $words[10], $words[12] ];
    }
});

if ($tuples) {
    print "Successfully inserted $tuples records\n";
} else {
    # do something usefull with @tuple_status, that contains the detailed results
}

$dbh->commit;
$dbh->disconnect;
```

Comment: thanks, i have this message  DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed at test_request.pl line 104, <FILE> line 1.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 1 bind variables when 0 are needed at test_request.pl line 104, <FILE> line 1.
Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect() of DBD::mysql::db handle database=slow_transdb;host=ip at test_requ

Comment: @dfg ert, That error doesn't come from GMB's code. GMB's code provides 3 values when 3 are needed (not 0 and 1 as you claim)

Comment: i have new message @ikegami  DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 3 bind variables when 0 are needed at test_request.pl line 96, <FILE> line 1.
DBD::mysql::st execute failed: called with 3 bind variables when 0 are needed at test_request.pl line 96, <FILE> line 1.
Issuing rollback() due to DESTROY without explicit disconnect()

Comment: Still not coming from GBD's code. The error means the query you are using has no `?` in it, but you are passing three arguments to `execute`. In GBD's code, there are three `?` in the query, and three arguments are passed to `execute`.

Comment: i use 3 argument, i don't know why that put the message. $sth->execute("$word5-$word2-$word3 $word4", $word11, $word13);

Comment: You are probably not using the query I gave you - yours has no bind parameters at all, hence the error. Look at your `prepare` statement...PS : thanks @ikegami !

Comment: @dfg ert, I know you are passing three arguments to `execute`. I said you were. The problem is that there are no placeholders (`?`) in the query you are executing.

Comment: my prepare statement work well my $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `test_querry` (time, cstep, time_in_seconde) VALUES('$word5-$word2-$word3 $word4', $word11, $word13);");

Comment: As explained by @ikegami, this is not the query `INSERT query I gave you (mine has 3 `?` in it, yours has none). Please properly copy the code in my answer, then test it.

Comment: @dfg ert, It only *appears* to work well, but actually suffers from a nasty code injection bug. GMB fixed this by switching to using placeholders, and you should do the same.

Comment: @GMB your code work but that not commit my 80000 line in one commit, your code execute one line by one line so its slow

Comment: Updated my answer to demonstrate the use of DBI's `execute_array` method, that performs bulk database operations

Comment: @gmb i have this message : DBD::mysql::st execute_array failed: ArrayTupleFetch 'ARRAY(0x2129868)' is not a code ref or statement handle at test_request.pl line 91, <$file> line 83098.
 Use of uninitialized value $words[12] in substitution (s///) at test_request.pl line 15, <$file> line 33761.
Use of uninitialized value $words[12] in numeric gt (>) at test_request.pl line 17, <$file> line 33761.
Use of uninitialized value $words[4] in concatenation (.) or string at test_request.pl line 86, <$file> line 33761.

Comment: @GMB do you have any idea ?

Comment: @dfgert : I updated my answer, please check